# How practical is using a Wireless-N router together with a B and G router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I hope to use a Wireless N router to boost up the speed of wireless Internet, but there are some device that probably only supports B or G, such as iPhone, iPad, Wii, so if it is to replace the existing Wireless-B/G router, then some device won't work.

Is it practical to buy a Wireless-N router, and then just plug the existing wireless router to it, or if I am using AT&T's u-verse, which has a central Wireless-B/G router, then plug in a new Wireless-N router into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Wireless N routers also support B and G so you shouldn't need to chain your routers in order to provide the backward compatibility.

Wireless N is not going to give you better throughput for your Internet connection, though, unless your connection gets higher than ~50mpbs.  It'll certainly give you better throughput between your PC and the router, but the Internet line is still going to be your bottleneck.  Currently AT&T Uverse is offering up to 24mbps which is well within the limits of Wireless G.  A Wireless N router is not going to serve that to you any faster than a router with Wireless G.  The only benefit you'll get from the Wireless N is better LAN performance.

Comment: Somewhat minor nitpick - 802.11g claims a maximum raw data rate of 54 Mbps, but in real-world conditions and taking into account network overhead, the actual maximum possible speed is closer to 16-19 Mbps. So if you actually do have a connection over 20 Mbps, it's likely that you could see some speed increase from N.

Comment: yes, I think my current Wireless-G can allow up to about 1MB/s... true, it is mainly so that when I move a file from my notebook to the desktop, it can be much faster...

Comment: also, if I stay with AT&T u-verse, I probably will be stuck to using their wireless router... which is probably just B/G, so I need to get a Wireless-N access point or router and plug it into the u-verse router... i think.  Should that work?